# Report throwing type mismatch error at elaboration

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to debug some errors that are causing some variable width mismatch issues (the adding stage below).

To do this, I want to use `report` statements to output some variables used in the calculations of these variable widths.

However, for some reason, even the most simple report statement:

```vhdl
report "this is a message";
```

Is throwing this error:

> syntax error near report

> error type void does not match with a string literal

Any idea what could be causing this?

---

I'm using VHDL2008 in Xilinx Vivado.

The whole source file for reference:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.All;
use IEEE.math_real.all;
use work.functions.all;


entity averager is
    generic
    (
        buffer_len: positive := 32; -- MUST BE A POWER OF 2
        input_max: positive := integer'high / buffer_len -- Maximum value of one data input
    );
    port 
    (
        clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        tri : in STD_LOGIC; 
        reset: in std_logic;       
        data_in : in unsigned (get_min_counter_width(input_max) - 1 downto 0);
        avg_out : out unsigned (get_min_counter_width(input_max) - 1 downto 0)
     );
end averager;

architecture behavioral of averager is
    
    -- TODO - Add assert that buffer_len is power of 2


    constant input_width: positive := get_min_counter_width(input_max);
    constant accum_width: positive := get_min_counter_width(input_width * buffer_len); -- Done at synthesis time, perfomance non-critical
    constant avg_bitshift: positive := integer(ceil(log2(real(buffer_len)))); -- How much bitshift is needed for fast divide
    
    signal last_tri: std_logic := '0';
    
    subtype in_val is unsigned(input_width - 1 downto 0);
    type acc_buffer is array(buffer_len - 1 downto 0) of in_val;
    
    constant in_zero: in_val := to_unsigned(0,input_width);
    signal in_buffer: acc_buffer; -- Initialised in reset

    type state is (rst, idle, adding, writing);
    signal current_state: state := rst;
    signal next_state: state := rst;
    
    constant accum_zero: unsigned(accum_width - 1 downto 0) := to_unsigned(0,accum_width);
    signal accumulator: unsigned(accum_width - 1 downto 0) := accum_zero;
    

begin


    sync_proc: process(clk)
    begin
       if (rising_edge(clk)) then
           if (reset = '1') then
               last_tri <= '0';
                current_state <= rst;
            else
                last_tri <= tri;
                current_state <= next_state;
                if (last_tri = '0' and tri = '1') then
                    in_buffer <= in_buffer(in_buffer'high downto in_buffer'low + 1) & in_val(data_in);
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    next_state_decode: process(current_state, tri)
    begin
       next_state <= current_state;
       case(current_state) is
           when rst =>
               next_state <= idle;
           when idle => 
               if (last_tri = '0' and tri = '1') then
                   next_state <= adding;
               end if;
           when adding =>
                   next_state <= writing;
           when writing =>
                   next_state <= idle;     
       end case;
    end process;
    
    output_decode: process(current_state)
    begin
       next_state <= current_state;
       case(current_state) is
           when rst =>
               next_state <= idle;
               for i in in_buffer'high downto 0 loop
                    in_buffer(i) <= in_zero;
               end loop;
           when idle => 

           when adding =>
               for i in in_buffer'high downto 0 loop
                    accumulator <= unsigned(accumulator) + resize(unsigned(in_buffer(i)),accum_width);
               end loop;
           when writing =>
                   avg_out <= accumulator(accumulator'high downto accumulator'low + avg_bitshift);     
       end case;
    end process;
    
    
    report "this is a message";
    


end behavioral;
```

Comment: A report statement is a sequential statement. You have it in the architecture statement part which only contains concurrent statements.

Comment: while report on its own is sequential as pointed out by @user1155120, it also follows an assert statement that can be used as a concurrent statement. I suggest using `assert false report "this is a message";`

Comment: And here Tricky suggests using a concurrent assertion statement which is allowed in the architecture statement part and provides the same functionality in it's report clause when the assertion condition is guaranteed to evaluate to the Boolean FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `report` statement is a sequential statement and can be used in sequential blocks only.

You can't use a `report` statement in architecture code, which is for concurrent statements only.

A `report` statement is a sequential statement by itself.

An `assert` statement can be used in concurrent blocks. The message in the `report` clause of the assertion will be printed if the assertion is false.

VHDL has a constant, `false`, of boolean type which has the value False. So if an `assert false` is used, the message in the `report` clause will be printed always.

So an `assert false report "your message";` can also be used if you want to print a message in a concurrent block.

Comment: You misinterpreted that linked answer. The withdrawn IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis tells us report statements are ignored.

Comment: Closer. Sequential statements can also appear in subprograms (functions and procedures). I'd encourage the use of some authority other than a cult of personality (e.g. look it up in the standard).

Comment: A report statement also follows an assert statement, which can be used as a concurrent statement (VHDL 2008 LRM 11.5 ). The following will print a message at the start of simulation when inside an architectrure (and throw it as an INFO message in most synth tools) `assert false report "This is a message";`

Comment: Report on its own is not limited to process or procedures, it can also be used in a function.

Comment: VHDL has no type `false`. This is the value of the boolean type. Assert will print the report if the condition evaluates to false. Hence using `assert false` will always print the report statement. 
Reports are not ignored by synthesis tools, depending on where they are used. from experience, synthesis in both Quartus and Vivado can be halted on a failing concurrent assert or in an an initialisation function, and will also print the report message. Vivado used to have a bug where sequential asserts/reports would halt synth if they were had severity of error or failure.

Comment: For example, concurrent assert can be used to check for illegal combinations of generics to halt synthesis. eg. `assert G_SOME_VALUE > 5 and G_SOME_VALUE < 25 report "G_SOME_VALUE is out of range (6-24)" severity failure;`

Comment: @Tricky, thank you very much. I have modified my answer.